# Ember.run.end issue

Tags: ember.js, radio-button

After setting the value to ember radio button through valueBinding, calling Ember.run.end() to reflect the changed value in DOM.

But see the below error.
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'prev' of null 
wt's the issue here

```
  //Doing value binding here
    App.radioController.set('content', App.createRadioModel.create({ id:1 }));
    Ember.run.end();
  //Doing some css changes as soon as the value is updated onto the radio button.
  Ember.$(".view-radio").removeClass("modified","delete");
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling `Ember.run.end()` without a corresponding `Ember.run.start()`. The error you're seeing is probably because there isn't a current run loop.

If you're looking to manually sync bindings, you can use `Ember.run.sync()`. Otherwise, I'd suggest wrapping your code in an `Ember.run()` call like this:

```
Ember.run(function() {
  // your code here
});
```